# Issue with nested json column names using mongo db spark connector

Tags: mongodb, nested

Use Case : Extracting mongodb data and converting to string

Problem statement : When I am extracting mongodb data using `"spark.jars.packages"`,`"org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1"`
the nested array columns are coming as `"ScrubbedAddress": ["N", 6, "BALTIMORE"]` while non nested columns are showing up as `"ActiveIndicator": "Y"`

Requirement : Need the data inside array as `"ScrubbedAddress": ["AddressMatchLevelType": "N", "AddressMatchLevelNumber": 6,  "CityName": "BALTIMORE"]`
Have anyone of you noted this ...is this issue with mongo connector version?